# A one word name for "taking a root" operation?

Tags: terminology, radicals, article-writing

We have addition and subtraction, multiplication and division, But what about raising to a power and taking roots? I hear about "exponentiation" recently, a term that I don't recall being used before (like 15 or 20 years ago), I guess it's alright. But I wonder if there is a term for taking roots too. It's kind of strange that we don't have a simple name for this operation, like we do for other arithmetic operations.

Comment: Taking roots is also a form of exponentiation... I would just as soon use the same word.  That being said, there is nothing special about having a "simple" name beyond aesthetics.

Comment: @JMoravitz, the problem is, subtraction is addition too, and division is multiplication, and yet we have "subtraction" and "division" there. I think it's for a reason. There should be consistency.

Comment: Exponentiation is a far older term than that.

Comment: Radicalize would fit quite well, if we want to coin a word :)

Comment: "*There should be consistency*"  Why?  What benefit is there to having this word to describe something which is already easily referred to with two words rather than one?

Comment: @Jam - I  thought of "radicalize" or "radicalization" as a natural choice. +1 for that. Unfortunately, the term might create a negative impression in the current political climate in the US. I'm surprised there hasn't been more backlash over calculus instructors teaching their students how to "integrate." Oh well.

Comment: I can't find any common verb for this, and I don't think there is one. I've heard "square root" used as a verb very often, informally. Some people on [this forum](https://boards.straightdope.com/t/is-there-a-verb-form-for-square-root/426733/15) mentions reading "sqrt" as a verb like "squirt", which I'll admit I've done too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general English term is "root extraction" as in "We shall now extract the square/cube/$n$th root of the positive nonnegative real number $x$."

An example is offered by this paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2970154

Arnold Emch: Two Hydraulic Methods to Extract the nth Root of any Number

The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 8, No. 1 (Jan., 1901), pp. 10-12 (3 pages)

There are similar terms in the Nordic languages. In Danish the term for extracting, say, square root of a number is "at uddrage kvadratroden af et tal", where the verb "uddrage" is an archaic version of extraction.

Comment: I agree that "root extraction" is the traditional term. Of course, it may cause stress to students with odontophobia $\ddot{\smile}$.